# How to get all "dt" and "dd" elements Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the HTML code:

```
<ul id="current">
 <li class="session">
   <dl>
        <dt>Mumbai, Maharashtra, India</dt>
        <dd>Approximate location</dd>
        <dt>Safari on Mac OS X</dt>
        <dt>IP Address:</dt>
       <dd>110.227.252.240</dd>
   </dl>
  </li>
```

I want all `dt` and `dd` elements

Comment: there's `document.getElementsByTagName` or `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Using jQuery, something like `$('dd')` would work. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried with TagName("dt").innerHTML
but doesn't seems to work

Comment: @Jay what is `TagName` and what should `innerHTML` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following with `querySelectorAll()`:

```js
let dt = document.querySelectorAll('#current > .session > dl > dt');
let dd = document.querySelectorAll('#current > .session > dl > dd');

dt.forEach(function(el){
  el.style.color = 'blue';
});

dd.forEach(function(el){
  el.style.color = 'red';
});
```

```html
<ul id="current">
 <li class="session">
  <dl>
    <dt>Mumbai, Maharashtra, India</dt>
    <dd>Approximate location</dd>
    <dt>Safari on Mac OS X</dt>
    <dt>IP Address:</dt>
    <dd>110.227.252.240</dd>
  </dl>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all elements

```
 var x = document.querySelectorAll("dt");

 var y = document.querySelectorAll("dd");
```

If you want to change any of their properties use for loop

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.color = "red";
}
```